# How to get SQL query for product insert in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, database, sql, query

How to get SQL query for product insert in Magento 2 ?

I have multiple products around 10 Lakhs so i want to insert it using SQL query.

But how will i get the insert query of the product ?

Any Help is Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can import data from csv file https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/system/data-import.html

otherwise you can create a command object using  Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator to import huge amount of records.

example code: http://www.rosenborgsolutions.com/collection-walk-iterator.php